# Trigonometry Problem. Help me!

Tags: trigonometry

Simplify
 $$\frac{\cos^{2}a-\cot^{2}a +1}{\sin^{2}a + \tan^{2} a -1}$$

Please help me solve this problem

Comment: What are you trying to simplify it to?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

$$\frac{\cos^{2}(a)-\cot^{2}(a)+1}{\sin^{2}(a)+\tan^{2}(a)-1}=\frac{\cos^{2}(a)-\frac{\cos^{2}(a)}{\sin^{2}(a)}+1}{\sin^{2}(a)+\frac{\sin^{2}(a)}{\cos^{2}(a)}-1}$$

$$=\frac{\cos^{2}(a)\left(1-\frac{1}{\sin^{2}(a)}+\frac{1}{\cos^{2}(a)}\right)}{\sin^{2}(a)\left(1+\frac{1}{\cos^{2}(a)}-\frac{1}{\sin^{2}(a)}\right)}=\frac{\cos^{2}(a)\left(1-\csc^{2}(a)+\sec^{2}(a)\right)}{\sin^{2}(a)\left(1+\sec^{2}(a)-\csc^{2}(a)\right)}$$

$$=\frac{\cos^{2}(a)\left(1-\csc^{2}(a)+\sec^{2}(a)\right)}{\sin^{2}(a)\left(1-\csc^{2}(a)+\sec^{2}(a)\right)}=\frac{\cos^{2}(a)}{\sin^{2}(a)}$$

$$=\left(\frac{\cos(a)}{\sin(a)}\right)^{2}=\cot^{2}(a)$$

Comment: if OP is asking this question, it would help to add more detail in your answer, i.e. $\cot$ and $\tan$ derivations and how the two terms, which don't look equal, cancel out.

Comment: That's a good suggestion. I'll update my answer right away.

Comment: You're welcome. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Use

$\cot(\theta) = \frac{\cos(\theta)}{\sin(\theta)}$

$\tan(\theta) = \frac{\sin(\theta)}{\cos(\theta)}$

$\sin^2(\theta)+\cos^2(\theta)=1$

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to attack a tough one like this is to write everything in terms of $s \equiv \sin \alpha$, simplify the resulting compound fraction, and then at the end, see if you recognize some other trig functions in the answer.

Here we have 
$$
\frac{1-s^2-\frac{1-s^2}{s^2}+1}{s^2+\frac{s^s}{1-s^2}-2}
$$
which becomes (multiply numerator and denominator by $s^2(1-s^2)$)
$$
\frac{(3s^2 - s^4 -1)(1-s^2)}{3s^4-s^6-s^2} = \frac{1-s^2}{s^2} 
= \frac{\cos^2 \alpha}{\sin^2 \alpha} = \cot^2 \alpha
$$

Comment: I don't understand, Why sin^2 + tan^2 - 1 = sin^2 + sin^2/(1-sin^2) - 2 ?